# Running selenium test with maven-surefire-plugin or maven-failsafe-plugin?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, continuous-integration, automated-tests, integration-testing

i am confused between the concept of using  **maven-surefire-plugin** or **maven-failsafe-plugin** to run my **selenium tests** in **integration test phase** (without running unit tests)
i see some examples uses **maven-surefire-plugin** and other examples uses **maven-failsafe-plugin**

please advise with sample or link to configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/) for running selenium tests.

The failsafe plugin runs the tests in the integration-test phase, and does not fail the build when integration tests fail hence allowing maven to run the post-integration-test phase. failsafe plugin fails the build in the verify phase. This is important as one would usually do things like starting up the server/setting up data during the pre-integration-test phase, and shutdowns/cleanups at the post-integration-test phase while running selenium tests.

Look at the [usage of the failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) and the [maven lifecycles reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).